# Time-to-event prediction in the group with pre- and post-diagnosis records and the group without event occurrence as control

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models, epidemiology

I study the triggering of the difficult form (ineffective two treatments) in patients with joint disease. In this retrospective study, we have collected the dataset of ~150 patients diagnosed with this difficult form and 200 patients with remission (good effectivity of the treatment) – as control. Selected patients were examined regularly for ~10 years and each patient has five follow-up time points at least. Patients with the difficult form have time points before and after the diagnosis. At each time point, patients’ records include demographic characteristics (e.g., sex or age), basic biochemical blood tests (e.g., CRP or ESR), and clinical assessments (e.g., number of affected joints).

The main study questions are:

1. Which of these recorded parameters (e.g., CRP or the number of affected joints) are associated with the difficult form?
2. Are we able to predict the diagnosis of difficult form? How far in advance and with what accuracy?

I have screened many articles, manuals and forums, but I have not found any manual or workflow on how to analyse my data. Therefore, I would like to ask you whether you could recommend me a study dealing with this topic. I'm lost on some points, e.g.:

- Should I include a control group (patients in remission) in the analyses of the association or prediction?
- The majority of survival or time-to-event analyses assume the death of the patient, but our patients are still alive after the diagnosis (~10 years) and we have their records after the diagnosis of the difficult form. How to analyse data, which includes records after the diagnosis and compare it to a control group (patients in remission)?
- Which analyses would be the best to answer the study questions?

Honestly, I am not a professional statistician, but I am experienced in a large spectrum of various analyses. I would appreciate any comments or advice.